# positioning an absolute div over a fixed div with special overflow

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed `div` with a `max-height`, an `overflow-y: auto` and an `overflow-x: hidden`.

```
<div id="overlay">  <!-- position:fixed; -->

    <div class="close" >&times;</div> <!-- position:absolute; NOT WORKING -->

    <div id="overlay-content"> CONTENT HERE </div>
</div> 

<div id="mask"></div>  <!-- another position:fixed;  -->
```

I want to add a layer on top of my `id="overlay"` called `class="close"` and it's not going over.

If I put the following code

```
max-height: 50%;
height:auto !important;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
```

inside `#overlay-content` instead of inside `#overlay` then the (X) Circle appears on top, but the max-height and the `overflow-y: auto` doesn't work anymore...

JSFIDDLE:  https://jsfiddle.net/g5Lt5oak/8/

You'll see the problem with the (x) circle not going over the FIX div. How can I fix this?

```css
#mask { /* create are mask */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#overlay { 
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 17%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  max-height: 50%;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

#overlay-content {
  /*  max-height: 50%;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  */
}

.close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: -14px;
  background: #d1d1d1; /*#b1b1b1; */
  color: white;
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  -o-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.close: hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="close">&times;</div>
  <div id="overlay-content">  
    <br><img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
    <br><img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
    <br><img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="mask"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the position absolute div with a position relative div. Also set the width of the images inside the overlay-content to 100% and remove the first break line tag.

```
<style>
.overlay-content img{
width:100%;
}
</style>
<div id="overlay">
<div style="position:relative">
<div class="close">×</div>
<div id="overlay-content">      
<img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
<br><img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
<br><img src="http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/roundflower.jpg"><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```